# Generate JPG from SVG using Apache Batik

Tags: java, apache, svg, batik, image-transcoding

I'm trying to turn a *.svg* file into a *.jpg* or *.png* file. Right now I'm trying to use **Apache Batik Transcoder** ([Link](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)).

**This is my code right now:** (official code from [here](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html))

```
// Create a JPEG transcoder
JPEGTranscoder t = new JPEGTranscoder();

// Set the transcoding hints.
t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,
    new Float(.8));

// Create the transcoder input.
String svgURI = new File("C:/test.svg").toURL().toString();
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);

// Create the transcoder output.
OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("C:/out.jpg");
TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

// Save the image.
t.transcode(input, output);

// Flush and close the stream.
ostream.flush();
ostream.close();
System.exit(0);
```

But it gives my this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
>
> Enclosed Exception:
>
> null
>
> at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
>
> at SaveAsJPEG.main(SaveAsJPEG.java:27)

I don't know what to do as this is the code from their website (!). So if you know how to solve it or have another idea how I can turn my .svg pictures into .jpg and .png's let me know.

Comment: Are you familiar with JMagick (based on ImageMagick)?

Comment: Does file "C:/test.svg" exist?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes it exists

Comment: @Yaron never used it before, but you can explain it in an answer if you want, I am going to take a look at it

Comment: http://thinktibits.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/convert-png-to-jpeg-using-jmagick-java.html

Comment: @Yaron this code is old and doesn't work anymore as it seems. Could you give me somehting else?

Comment: @JetStream, sorry, I didn't pay attention, found another possible solution: https://github.com/bripkens/svg-export

Comment: @Yaron I also saw this but it uses Apache Batik and the code is outdated for the latest version of Apache. Problem is there is no documentation so I don't know which version of Batik I should import. The project itself doesn't have the working Batik version attached to it

Comment: @Yaron Found a slution which also "repairs" SVG-Export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have now found the solution to my problem. It seems like **Batik 1.8** (which I have used) does not work properly (or at least does not work in the way they say it on their API page.

I now used **Batik 1.7** wich works just fine. So now everything is fine and to everyone who wants to use Batik: I suggest you to use 1.7 because the documentation is not about 1.8.

Comment: which java version you are using??

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved if you add `batik-codec` to `maven` instead of the `transcoder`.